# How to get individual error labels to show C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, label

I am working on a contact page and would like some help please on how to display error labels at individual times when the textboxes are empty. I have used 3 textboxes. I am a new student in C# asp.net. I really appreciate your time and help. Thanks!

```
 //if no or incorrect entries are entered panel with red message using a label appears to remind the user of 
    //if name, email, enquiry is blank error labels show up
    if (nameContactUsTextBox.Text == "" && emailContactUsTextBox.Text == "" && enquiryContactUsTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        nameErrorLabel.Visible = true;
        emailErrorLabel.Visible = true;
        equiryErrorLabel.Visible = true;
    }

    if (nameContactUsTextBox.Text != "" && emailContactUsTextBox.Text == "" && enquiryContactUsTextBox.Text == "")
    {

        emailErrorLabel.Visible = true;
        equiryErrorLabel.Visible = true;
    }

    if (nameContactUsTextBox.Text == "" && emailContactUsTextBox.Text != "" && enquiryContactUsTextBox.Text == "")
    {
        nameErrorLabel.Visible = true;
        equiryErrorLabel.Visible = true;
    }

    if (nameContactUsTextBox.Text == "" && emailContactUsTextBox.Text == "" && enquiryContactUsTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        nameErrorLabel.Visible = true;
        emailErrorLabel.Visible = true;

    }
```

aspx file

```
<p>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="boring">Name</td>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:TextBox ID="nameContactUsTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="boring" ToolTip="Enter Name" Width="441px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="nameErrorLabel" runat="server" CssClass="redalert" Text="*complete name" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="boring">E-Mail</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="emailContactUsTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="boring" ToolTip="Enter Email" Width="443px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="emailErrorLabel" runat="server" CssClass="redalert" Text="*complete email" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="boring">Enquiry</td>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="enquiryContactUsTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="classic" Height="158px" ToolTip="Enter Enquiry" Width="441px"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Label ID="equiryErrorLabel" runat="server" CssClass="redalert" Text="*complete enquiry" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style5"></td>
            <td class="auto-style2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="smallheader" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style5">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="auto-style2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style5" colspan="2">
                <asp:Button ID="sendButton" runat="server" CssClass="smallheader" OnClick="sendButton_Click" Text="Send" ToolTip="Sending to NeoMan!" Width="200px" />
                <asp:Button ID="homeButton" runat="server" CssClass="smallheader" OnClick="homeButton_Click" Text="Home" ToolTip="Continue Shopping With NeoMan" Width="200px" />
                <asp:Button ID="resetButton" runat="server" CssClass="smallheader" OnClick="resetButton_Click" Text="Reset Form" ToolTip="Clear Form" Width="200px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

Comment: Can you post your aspx file as well ?

Comment: you fine with jquery ? This can be done easily using span tag with id and with a error check condition  .

Comment: Are you using forms, MVC or some other pattern?

Comment: What help? What's the problem? Where's the error?

Comment: Your code seems fine, What seems to be the issue?

Comment: The error labels do not come up individually but altogether. I want the error labels to show only when there is no text?

Comment: Try to use validators, or use some javascript to do this validation on client side. This way you will avoid unnecessary postback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `TextChangedEvent` like so:

```
protected void nameContactUsTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    nameErrorLabel.Visible = nameContactUsTextBox.Text == "";
}
```

And add the textchanged-event for each of the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft already have buil ib validators that you can use to do this sort of task. To make sure that the field is not empty use the Required Field validator see this example on the w3c school website http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_reqfieldvalidator.
For more complex validation use can use the regular expression validator. check the msdn website(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this it quite straight forward.
you can also investigate the JQuery validator it is quite flexible to do more interesting validation.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to hide labels when they're not supposed to be shown, not only hide it. Change `if`s to `if-else`s and add a summary else condition

```
else
{
    nameErrorLabel.Visible = false;
    emailErrorLabel.Visible = false;
    equiryErrorLabel.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: In his aspx file he has set those error label's visibility to false

Answer (score 0):

You should use the 
    placeholder
property of the textbox to display the type of value you need entered and examine those answers with jquery either after the boxes lose focus or upon a click of a button.  If you need some sample code let me know